# How to fix this error in node.js i reinstalled node.js and it still dont work

Tags: node.js

I was trying to run a js file from this source code to have a discord bot  https://github.com/TacoShack/TacoShack-Classic

```
C:\Users\secretname>node main.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\secretname\main.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I did this following the instructions

```
C:\Users\secretname>npm install C:\Users\secretname\Downloads\TacoShack-Classic-master\TacoShack-Classic-master
npm WARN deprecated discord.js@12.5.3: no longer supported

added 61 packages, and audited 63 packages in 13s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to navigate to the directory

`cd C:\Users\`secretname`\Downloads\TacoShack-Classic-master\TacoShack-Classic-master`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).